# Export data from datagridview to csv with scientific notation

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I would like to allow the user in my application to select to export data to scientific notation, but only if it is a column of doubles. I plan on doing a simple check:

```
foreach (dataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns
{
    if (col.GetType() == typeOf(Double)
     {
         // Perform data conversion from e.g 22.56 to scientific
     }
 }
```

What is the best way to do this? String.Format? Are there also additional checks I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the string.Format indeed :

string.Format("{0:E2}", MyNumber);

have a look at msdn Standard Numeric Format Strings for more information

Comment: Is MyNumber the parsed value  from each cell?

Comment: It is the data from your col, you need to change MyNumber to point to your cell value

Comment: Are there other checks I need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by checks? Can you edit your code with what you have now? The conversion is only for display right?